# Specifying content of an iframe instead of the src attribute to a page

Tags: html, iframe

I'm currently working on a form which includes some file inputs to upload pictures. There is an `onchange()` event for those inputs that submits the pictures to an `iframe`, then dynamically loads the uploaded pictures into the form, with fields to be modified for them (like *name* and *geo-localization*).

Since I can't nest forms, the `file_input` is also contained in an `iframe`. In the end I use an `iframe` inside of another `iframe`. So I have something like this:

```
<form>
<!-- LOTS OF FIELDS!! -->
<iframe src="file_input_url">
<!-- iframe which loads a page of a form with a file input-->
</iframe>
</form>
```

and the HTML loaded into the `iframe` is something like (excluding the `html`, `head` and `body` tags)

```
<form target="upload_iframe">
<input type="file" onchange="this.form.submit()">
</form>
<iframe name="upload_iframe"></iframe>
```

This works great, except for the fact that it takes a couple seconds to load the first `iframe`, so the file input does not load with the rest of the page. This is not visually ideal. I could solve it if I could specify the `iframe` content without needing to load another page (specified by `file_input_url` in the first `iframe`).

Is there a way to specify the `iframe` content in the same document, or can it only be specified with the `src` attribute, requiring the load of another page?

Comment: It shouldn't take "a couple of seconds" to load that iframe. I'd expect it to be more like a tenth of a millisecond plus the "time to bite bite" (which also should be milliseconds). You should investigate what's causing all the lag - probably something wrong with your server.

Comment: there is also one strange way 
```<iframe src="javascript:parent._renderMe()"></iframe>``` and in js:
```function _renderMe() {return String(Math.random()}```

Answer (score 123):

You can `.write()` the content into the iframe document. Example:

```
<iframe id="FileFrame" src="about:blank"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var doc = document.getElementById('FileFrame').contentWindow.document;
   doc.open();
   doc.write('<html><head><title></title></head><body>Hello world.</body></html>');
   doc.close();
</script>
```

Comment: Had thought about this possibility, however, the html that has to be loaded into the iframe is complex, and handling it entirely in javascript in order to write it to the iframe would obscure the implementation too much (up to the point that I prefer to leave it as it is).

Comment: @orlox: Get your content from the server using Ajax and inject it. If you don't want to go that way, make a hidden `div` element with your content and place its content in the `iframe` between `<body>` and `</body>`.

Comment: The more I learn about iframes restrictions the more I hate them

Comment: @stackular I he can use ajax he can also simple `src` in iframe.

Comment: This solution is great.  I haven't tested in all browsers yet but this allowed me to write full HTML documents with css attributes in the body tag and honor the attributes.  Unlike all the other solutions, this seems to write HTML code to the frame that includes head, body tags without manipulating it to some degree.  It also didn't affect various encodings I was dealing with where JS solutions that call `escape()` turned UTF-8 into `%u####` that didn't display properly in the frame.

Comment: How do I escape single quotes using this method? Some of them are HTML-important (e.g. class='example'), some are CSS-important (e.g. font-family: 'Verdana';) and some are content (e.g. George O'Malley).

Comment: @Dan: To escape any value to be used in an apostrophe delimited JavaScript string, you first escape backslashes, then apostrophes. For example using C# to output a string in the code: `doc.write('<%= html.Replace("\\", "\\\\").Replace("'", "\\'") %>');`.

Comment: @Guffa I figured half of that out on my own (through trial-and-error), but not the other. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Thanks, works great. I also had issues escaping the </script> tag and wrapped the whole thing in commented out HTML comments. As per this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28643272/how-to-include-an-escapedscript-script-tag-in-a-javascript-variable /*<!--*/
var script = '<script async src="//somesite.com/feed/livetrend.js"></script>';
/*-->*/

Comment: @DanBechard you don't need to escape any quotes. Just wrap everything in backticks (ES2105 templates) - read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals.
`doc.write(\`<div class="username" style="font-family:'Verdana';">George O'Malley</div>\``)

Answer (score 60):

iframe now supports [srcdoc](http://caniuse.com/#feat=iframe-srcdoc) which  can be used to specify the HTML content of the page to show in the inline frame.

Comment: IE doesn't support this right not but you could check [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=iframe-srcdoc) for the latest status on it.

Comment: [Documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-srcdoc)

Comment: Note that with srcdoc you don't need any js: <iframe srcdoc="<!DOCTYPE html><p>Hello World!</p>"></iframe>

Answer (score 37):

You can use `data:` URL in the `src`:

```js
var html = 'Hello from <img src="http://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico" alt="SO">';
var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
iframe.src = 'data:text/html,' + encodeURIComponent(html);
```

```html
<iframe></iframe>
```

[Difference between srcdoc=“…” and src=“data:text/html,…” in an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19739001/which-is-the-difference-between-srcdoc-and-src-datatext-html-in-an).

[Convert HTML to data:text/html link using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238890/convert-html-to-datatext-html-link-using-javascript).

Comment: You don't even need any JavaScript: the `src` attribute can be specified inline if escaped e.g. using `rawurlencode` in PHP: `<iframe src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars('data:text/html,' . rawurlencode($content)); ?>"></iframe>`

Comment: Microsoft added support for this at pretty much the same time as they added support for `srcdoc`, and `srcdoc` is the better way to do this. Data URLs are only widely supported for images and CSS - as far as I know no version of Internet Explorer supports them in an iframe.

Comment: Isn't there some length restriction with the `src` attribute?

Answer (score 6):

In combination with what Guffa described, you could use the technique described in
[Explanation of <script type = "text/template"> ... </script>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912586/explanation-of-script-type-text-template-script) to store the HTML document in a special `script` element (see the link for an explanation on how this works). That's a lot easier than storing the HTML document in a string.

Comment: On second thought, that wouldn't work very well for a full HTML document. Tags such as `<html>`, `<body>`, `<script>` would only confuse the browser, breaking the rendering of the document.

Comment: That does not appear to be an issue, the HTML tags inside scripts are ignored.

Comment: You're right :) I hadn't actually tried the technique yet when I wrote that, and must have picked up that assumption from somewhere. I later found out that anything within a `<script>` tag would be ignored by the browser.. Thanks for correcting me!

Comment: You can include the content within the iframe itself, e.g.  `<iframe id="my-frame"><html><body><b>Hello!</b></body></html></iframe><script type="text/javascript">
    var iframe = document.getElementById("my-frame")
    iframe.setAttribute("srcdoc", iframe.innerHTML)
</script>`

Answer (score 1):

Necromancing. 
Yes, you can, **and without JavaScript** ! 
You can specify base64 or just data-content in the src url.
e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />



<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>How to embed an SVG sandboxed</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

  <!-- Add appropriate styles to the iframe to control its appearance -->
  <style>
      html, body
      {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          margin:0;
          padding: 0;
      }


  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <!-- Create an iframe to sandbox user-uploaded SVGs -->
    <!--
    <object style="width: 30px;" data="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20437.00412%20279.53189%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23FF00FF%22%20d%3D%22M251.99573%20182.23684h-5.27915V29.05126h5.27915zm38.7702-7.40139c0%205.27389-3.9857%208.7687-8.5786%208.7687-5.0416%200-8.6315-3.77461-8.6315-8.7687%200-5.27916%203.9858-8.76869%208.6315-8.76869%204.5929%200%208.5786%203.48953%208.5786%208.76869m-1.8741%200c0-4.27084-2.9563-7.24829-6.7045-7.24829-3.801%200-6.7574%202.97745-6.7574%207.24829%200%203.98577%202.5816%207.24302%206.7574%207.24302%203.7482%200%206.7045-2.95106%206.7045-7.24302m-8.4414.86579v4.14942h-1.5943v-9.70839h3.6796c2.344%200%203.5423.82355%203.5423%202.79268%200%201.75796-1.0769%202.48649-2.534%202.65014l2.7188%204.26557h-1.8055l-2.5076-4.14942zm0-1.35675h1.7791c1.1984%200%202.2542-.12142%202.2542-1.52568%200-1.17197-1.1508-1.31451-2.1116-1.31451h-1.9217zM.1003%20277.20906l1.84243-4.64039c.93969.69157%202.10639%201.27228%203.50537%201.74212%201.40954.45401%202.67126.68102%203.77988.68102%201.96913%200%203.55288-.53848%204.74597-1.61543%201.1931-1.07695%201.78964-2.44425%201.78964-4.11247%200-1.24588-.33787-2.39674-1.00832-3.45257-.6599-1.07695-2.32283-2.24365-4.99409-3.51065l-2.97745-1.38314c-2.52344-1.17726-4.28669-2.57096-5.29501-4.18638C.49624%20255.11574%200%20253.17301%200%20250.90297c0-2.75573.97136-5.04161%202.92466-6.85764%201.95329-1.81603%204.45561-2.72405%207.51753-2.72405%204.08608%200%206.92627.6599%208.52586%201.99025l-1.48873%204.38698c-.67573-.48568-1.69989-.95553-3.07775-1.40953-1.37787-.45401-2.65542-.68102-3.83268-.68102-1.71573%200-3.07247.48569-4.05968%201.46233-.97664.97665-1.46761%202.22781-1.46761%203.75877%200%20.93969.17949%201.8002.5332%202.57095.3537.77604.83939%201.4201%201.46233%201.94274.63878.52263%201.93217%201.25116%203.88019%202.19613l3.03024%201.43593c2.52344%201.1931%204.28668%202.62375%205.295%204.28669%201.02416%201.6471%201.53624%203.75349%201.54152%206.3086%200%202.77156-1.11919%205.12607-3.35755%207.05825-2.21725%201.93217-5.1947%202.89826-8.92707%202.90354-3.27837%200-6.0816-.77604-8.39916-2.32283m57.49013%202.19613H56.0014l-8.80037-25.47726-8.22494%2025.47726h-1.58903L25.73594%20241.9495h5.24749l7.41195%2025.80457%208.12464-25.80457h1.76324l8.01905%2025.75178%207.54393-25.75178h5.2475zM77.1867%20241.9495h5.0416v36.94889h-5.0416zm15.95892%2035.25956%201.84243-4.64039c.93969.69157%202.11167%201.27228%203.50537%201.74212%201.41481.45401%202.67653.68102%203.78516.68102%201.96385%200%203.5476-.53848%204.74069-1.61543%201.19309-1.07695%201.78964-2.44425%201.78964-4.11247%200-1.24588-.33259-2.39674-1.00832-3.45257-.65462-1.07695-2.32284-2.24365-4.9941-3.51065l-2.97745-1.38314c-2.51816-1.17726-4.28668-2.57096-5.295-4.18638-.99248-1.61543-1.48873-3.55816-1.48873-5.8282%200-2.75573.97665-5.04161%202.92466-6.85764%201.9533-1.81603%204.45562-2.72405%207.51754-2.72405%204.08607%200%206.92626.6599%208.52585%201.99025l-1.48872%204.38698c-.67046-.48568-1.69462-.95553-3.07776-1.40953-1.37786-.45401-2.65542-.68102-3.83267-.68102-1.71573%200-3.0672.48569-4.05968%201.46233-.97665.97665-1.46233%202.22781-1.46233%203.75877%200%20.93969.17421%201.8002.52792%202.57095.3537.77604.83938%201.4201%201.46232%201.94274.63878.52263%201.93218%201.25116%203.88547%202.19613l3.02496%201.43593c2.52345%201.1931%204.28669%202.62375%205.30029%204.28669%201.02416%201.6471%201.53624%203.75349%201.53624%206.3086%200%202.77156-1.11919%205.12607-3.35228%207.05825-2.22253%201.93217-5.19998%202.89826-8.93235%202.90354-3.27836%200-6.07632-.77604-8.39915-2.32283m28.97735%200%201.84243-4.64039c.93969.69157%202.10638%201.27228%203.50536%201.74212%201.41482.45401%202.67126.68102%203.78517.68102%201.96385%200%203.5476-.53848%204.74069-1.61543%201.19309-1.07695%201.78963-2.44425%201.78963-4.11247%200-1.24588-.33786-2.39674-1.00832-3.45257-.65461-1.07695-2.32283-2.24365-4.99409-3.51065l-2.97745-1.38314c-2.52344-1.17726-4.28668-2.57096-5.295-4.18638-.99249-1.61543-1.48873-3.55816-1.48873-5.8282%200-2.75573.97665-5.04161%202.92466-6.85764%201.95329-1.81603%204.45562-2.72405%207.51753-2.72405%204.08608%200%206.92627.6599%208.52586%201.99025l-1.48873%204.38698c-.67573-.48568-1.69989-.95553-3.07775-1.40953-1.37786-.45401-2.65542-.68102-3.83268-.68102-1.71573%200-3.06719.48569-4.05968%201.46233-.97664.97665-1.4676%202.22781-1.4676%203.75877%200%20.93969.17949%201.8002.53319%202.57095.35371.77604.83939%201.4201%201.46233%201.94274.63878.52263%201.93218%201.25116%203.88547%202.19613l3.02496%201.43593c2.52344%201.1931%204.28668%202.62375%205.29501%204.28669%201.02943%201.6471%201.53623%203.75349%201.54151%206.3086%200%202.77156-1.11918%205.12607-3.35755%207.05825-2.21725%201.93217-5.1947%202.89826-8.92707%202.90354-3.27836%200-6.07632-.77604-8.39915-2.32283m48.66336-12.53275v14.22208h-5.04161V241.9495c3.81684-.16893%206.11856-.2534%206.91043-.2534%2010.72727%200%2016.0909%203.58983%2016.0909%2010.7695%200%208.30941-4.74069%2012.45884-14.22735%2012.45884-.57015%200-1.81604-.0792-3.73237-.24813m0-18.18673v13.64665l3.38394.24812c6.25054%200%209.38108-2.46009%209.38108-7.38555%200-4.50841-3.34171-6.76262-10.01458-6.76262-.67045%200-1.58903.0845-2.75044.2534m44.78317%2032.40881-9.86148-15.8639c-1.12975%200-2.90883-.0845-5.3478-.2534v16.1173h-5.04688V241.9495l3.91186-.17421c2.43897-.13726%204.21277-.20061%205.3214-.20589%208.87956%200%2013.31934%203.53176%2013.31934%2010.59529%200%202.31755-.71797%204.41338-2.14334%206.28221-1.43066%201.84771-3.13055%202.99856-5.09968%203.45257l10.72199%2016.99892zm-15.20928-32.40881v12.00483c1.20893.16893%202.38618.2534%203.53176.2534%203.02497%200%205.22638-.48568%206.60424-1.46233%201.38314-.97665%202.06943-2.71877%202.06943-5.2211%200-2.06943-.73908-3.55815-2.21725-4.46617-1.48344-.90802-3.81683-1.36203-7.01073-1.36203-.5068%200-1.49928.0845-2.97745.2534m29.78506-4.54008h5.04688v36.94889h-5.04688zm46.47775%2036.94889-4.387-23.72986-8.0718%2024.23666h-1.2617l-8.2989-24.23666-4.2866%2023.72986h-4.79354l6.91044-36.94889h2.2964l8.8004%2026.96071%208.1246-26.96071h2.2701l7.4911%2036.94889zm20.5888-32.40881v10.26798h12.2054v4.28669h-12.2054v13.31406h16.7455v4.54008h-21.7924V241.9495h22.0722v4.54008zm39.1028%2030.71948%201.8424-4.64039c.9397.69157%202.1064%201.27228%203.5054%201.74212%201.4095.45401%202.6712.68102%203.7799.68102%201.9691%200%203.5475-.53848%204.7459-1.61543%201.1931-1.07695%201.7897-2.44425%201.7897-4.11247%200-1.24588-.3379-2.39674-1.0084-3.45257-.6599-1.07695-2.3228-2.24365-4.9941-3.51065l-2.9774-1.38314c-2.5234-1.17726-4.2867-2.57096-5.295-4.18638-.9925-1.61543-1.4887-3.55816-1.4887-5.8282%200-2.75573.9713-5.04161%202.9246-6.85764%201.948-1.81603%204.4557-2.72405%207.5176-2.72405%204.086%200%206.9262.6599%208.5258%201.99025l-1.4887%204.38698c-.6757-.48568-1.6999-.95553-3.0778-1.40953-1.3831-.45401-2.6554-.68102-3.8379-.68102-1.7105%200-3.0672.48569-4.0544%201.46233-.9767.97665-1.4676%202.22781-1.4676%203.75877%200%20.93969.1795%201.8002.5332%202.57095.3537.77604.8394%201.4201%201.4623%201.94274.6388.52263%201.9322%201.25116%203.8802%202.19613l3.0302%201.43593c2.5235%201.1931%204.2867%202.62375%205.295%204.28669%201.0242%201.6471%201.5363%203.75349%201.5416%206.3086%200%202.77156-1.1192%205.12607-3.3576%207.05825-2.2172%201.93217-5.1947%202.89826-8.9271%202.90354-3.2783%200-6.0763-.77604-8.3991-2.32283m30.4924-35.25956h5.0417v36.94889h-5.0417zm29.0249%204.54008v32.40881h-5.0416v-32.40881h-11.7567v-4.54008h29.0829v4.54008zm24.1522%200v10.26798h12.2054v4.28669h-12.2054v13.31406h16.7455v4.54008h-21.7924V241.9495h22.0669v4.54008zM64.84929%20211.18252c48.61584-13.77863%2099.91351-21.14835%20152.93218-21.14835%2053.21396%200%20104.70176%207.42779%20153.47066%2021.30144l-1.2934%204.5612c-48.3572-13.75751-99.4067-21.12194-152.17726-21.12194-52.5805%200-103.44527%207.30636-151.63879%2020.96885zm171.30368-28.94568h-5.28444V0h5.28444zm-15.84806%200h-5.27916V0h5.27916zm-15.84806%200h-5.28444V0h5.28444zm-15.84278%200h-5.28444V52.82335h5.28444zm-15.84806%200h-5.27916V52.82335h5.27916zm95.07782%200h-5.2845V29.05126h5.2845z%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fsvg%3E"></object>
        -->
    <iframe style="outline: 1px solid crimson; width: 30px; height: 30px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20437.00412%20279.53189%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23FF00FF%22%20d%3D%22M251.99573%20182.23684h-5.27915V29.05126h5.27915zm38.7702-7.40139c0%205.27389-3.9857%208.7687-8.5786%208.7687-5.0416%200-8.6315-3.77461-8.6315-8.7687%200-5.27916%203.9858-8.76869%208.6315-8.76869%204.5929%200%208.5786%203.48953%208.5786%208.76869m-1.8741%200c0-4.27084-2.9563-7.24829-6.7045-7.24829-3.801%200-6.7574%202.97745-6.7574%207.24829%200%203.98577%202.5816%207.24302%206.7574%207.24302%203.7482%200%206.7045-2.95106%206.7045-7.24302m-8.4414.86579v4.14942h-1.5943v-9.70839h3.6796c2.344%200%203.5423.82355%203.5423%202.79268%200%201.75796-1.0769%202.48649-2.534%202.65014l2.7188%204.26557h-1.8055l-2.5076-4.14942zm0-1.35675h1.7791c1.1984%200%202.2542-.12142%202.2542-1.52568%200-1.17197-1.1508-1.31451-2.1116-1.31451h-1.9217zM.1003%20277.20906l1.84243-4.64039c.93969.69157%202.10639%201.27228%203.50537%201.74212%201.40954.45401%202.67126.68102%203.77988.68102%201.96913%200%203.55288-.53848%204.74597-1.61543%201.1931-1.07695%201.78964-2.44425%201.78964-4.11247%200-1.24588-.33787-2.39674-1.00832-3.45257-.6599-1.07695-2.32283-2.24365-4.99409-3.51065l-2.97745-1.38314c-2.52344-1.17726-4.28669-2.57096-5.29501-4.18638C.49624%20255.11574%200%20253.17301%200%20250.90297c0-2.75573.97136-5.04161%202.92466-6.85764%201.95329-1.81603%204.45561-2.72405%207.51753-2.72405%204.08608%200%206.92627.6599%208.52586%201.99025l-1.48873%204.38698c-.67573-.48568-1.69989-.95553-3.07775-1.40953-1.37787-.45401-2.65542-.68102-3.83268-.68102-1.71573%200-3.07247.48569-4.05968%201.46233-.97664.97665-1.46761%202.22781-1.46761%203.75877%200%20.93969.17949%201.8002.5332%202.57095.3537.77604.83939%201.4201%201.46233%201.94274.63878.52263%201.93217%201.25116%203.88019%202.19613l3.03024%201.43593c2.52344%201.1931%204.28668%202.62375%205.295%204.28669%201.02416%201.6471%201.53624%203.75349%201.54152%206.3086%200%202.77156-1.11919%205.12607-3.35755%207.05825-2.21725%201.93217-5.1947%202.89826-8.92707%202.90354-3.27837%200-6.0816-.77604-8.39916-2.32283m57.49013%202.19613H56.0014l-8.80037-25.47726-8.22494%2025.47726h-1.58903L25.73594%20241.9495h5.24749l7.41195%2025.80457%208.12464-25.80457h1.76324l8.01905%2025.75178%207.54393-25.75178h5.2475zM77.1867%20241.9495h5.0416v36.94889h-5.0416zm15.95892%2035.25956%201.84243-4.64039c.93969.69157%202.11167%201.27228%203.50537%201.74212%201.41481.45401%202.67653.68102%203.78516.68102%201.96385%200%203.5476-.53848%204.74069-1.61543%201.19309-1.07695%201.78964-2.44425%201.78964-4.11247%200-1.24588-.33259-2.39674-1.00832-3.45257-.65462-1.07695-2.32284-2.24365-4.9941-3.51065l-2.97745-1.38314c-2.51816-1.17726-4.28668-2.57096-5.295-4.18638-.99248-1.61543-1.48873-3.55816-1.48873-5.8282%200-2.75573.97665-5.04161%202.92466-6.85764%201.9533-1.81603%204.45562-2.72405%207.51754-2.72405%204.08607%200%206.92626.6599%208.52585%201.99025l-1.48872%204.38698c-.67046-.48568-1.69462-.95553-3.07776-1.40953-1.37786-.45401-2.65542-.68102-3.83267-.68102-1.71573%200-3.0672.48569-4.05968%201.46233-.97665.97665-1.46233%202.22781-1.46233%203.75877%200%20.93969.17421%201.8002.52792%202.57095.3537.77604.83938%201.4201%201.46232%201.94274.63878.52263%201.93218%201.25116%203.88547%202.19613l3.02496%201.43593c2.52345%201.1931%204.28669%202.62375%205.30029%204.28669%201.02416%201.6471%201.53624%203.75349%201.53624%206.3086%200%202.77156-1.11919%205.12607-3.35228%207.05825-2.22253%201.93217-5.19998%202.89826-8.93235%202.90354-3.27836%200-6.07632-.77604-8.39915-2.32283m28.97735%200%201.84243-4.64039c.93969.69157%202.10638%201.27228%203.50536%201.74212%201.41482.45401%202.67126.68102%203.78517.68102%201.96385%200%203.5476-.53848%204.74069-1.61543%201.19309-1.07695%201.78963-2.44425%201.78963-4.11247%200-1.24588-.33786-2.39674-1.00832-3.45257-.65461-1.07695-2.32283-2.24365-4.99409-3.51065l-2.97745-1.38314c-2.52344-1.17726-4.28668-2.57096-5.295-4.18638-.99249-1.61543-1.48873-3.55816-1.48873-5.8282%200-2.75573.97665-5.04161%202.92466-6.85764%201.95329-1.81603%204.45562-2.72405%207.51753-2.72405%204.08608%200%206.92627.6599%208.52586%201.99025l-1.48873%204.38698c-.67573-.48568-1.69989-.95553-3.07775-1.40953-1.37786-.45401-2.65542-.68102-3.83268-.68102-1.71573%200-3.06719.48569-4.05968%201.46233-.97664.97665-1.4676%202.22781-1.4676%203.75877%200%20.93969.17949%201.8002.53319%202.57095.35371.77604.83939%201.4201%201.46233%201.94274.63878.52263%201.93218%201.25116%203.88547%202.19613l3.02496%201.43593c2.52344%201.1931%204.28668%202.62375%205.29501%204.28669%201.02943%201.6471%201.53623%203.75349%201.54151%206.3086%200%202.77156-1.11918%205.12607-3.35755%207.05825-2.21725%201.93217-5.1947%202.89826-8.92707%202.90354-3.27836%200-6.07632-.77604-8.39915-2.32283m48.66336-12.53275v14.22208h-5.04161V241.9495c3.81684-.16893%206.11856-.2534%206.91043-.2534%2010.72727%200%2016.0909%203.58983%2016.0909%2010.7695%200%208.30941-4.74069%2012.45884-14.22735%2012.45884-.57015%200-1.81604-.0792-3.73237-.24813m0-18.18673v13.64665l3.38394.24812c6.25054%200%209.38108-2.46009%209.38108-7.38555%200-4.50841-3.34171-6.76262-10.01458-6.76262-.67045%200-1.58903.0845-2.75044.2534m44.78317%2032.40881-9.86148-15.8639c-1.12975%200-2.90883-.0845-5.3478-.2534v16.1173h-5.04688V241.9495l3.91186-.17421c2.43897-.13726%204.21277-.20061%205.3214-.20589%208.87956%200%2013.31934%203.53176%2013.31934%2010.59529%200%202.31755-.71797%204.41338-2.14334%206.28221-1.43066%201.84771-3.13055%202.99856-5.09968%203.45257l10.72199%2016.99892zm-15.20928-32.40881v12.00483c1.20893.16893%202.38618.2534%203.53176.2534%203.02497%200%205.22638-.48568%206.60424-1.46233%201.38314-.97665%202.06943-2.71877%202.06943-5.2211%200-2.06943-.73908-3.55815-2.21725-4.46617-1.48344-.90802-3.81683-1.36203-7.01073-1.36203-.5068%200-1.49928.0845-2.97745.2534m29.78506-4.54008h5.04688v36.94889h-5.04688zm46.47775%2036.94889-4.387-23.72986-8.0718%2024.23666h-1.2617l-8.2989-24.23666-4.2866%2023.72986h-4.79354l6.91044-36.94889h2.2964l8.8004%2026.96071%208.1246-26.96071h2.2701l7.4911%2036.94889zm20.5888-32.40881v10.26798h12.2054v4.28669h-12.2054v13.31406h16.7455v4.54008h-21.7924V241.9495h22.0722v4.54008zm39.1028%2030.71948%201.8424-4.64039c.9397.69157%202.1064%201.27228%203.5054%201.74212%201.4095.45401%202.6712.68102%203.7799.68102%201.9691%200%203.5475-.53848%204.7459-1.61543%201.1931-1.07695%201.7897-2.44425%201.7897-4.11247%200-1.24588-.3379-2.39674-1.0084-3.45257-.6599-1.07695-2.3228-2.24365-4.9941-3.51065l-2.9774-1.38314c-2.5234-1.17726-4.2867-2.57096-5.295-4.18638-.9925-1.61543-1.4887-3.55816-1.4887-5.8282%200-2.75573.9713-5.04161%202.9246-6.85764%201.948-1.81603%204.4557-2.72405%207.5176-2.72405%204.086%200%206.9262.6599%208.5258%201.99025l-1.4887%204.38698c-.6757-.48568-1.6999-.95553-3.0778-1.40953-1.3831-.45401-2.6554-.68102-3.8379-.68102-1.7105%200-3.0672.48569-4.0544%201.46233-.9767.97665-1.4676%202.22781-1.4676%203.75877%200%20.93969.1795%201.8002.5332%202.57095.3537.77604.8394%201.4201%201.4623%201.94274.6388.52263%201.9322%201.25116%203.8802%202.19613l3.0302%201.43593c2.5235%201.1931%204.2867%202.62375%205.295%204.28669%201.0242%201.6471%201.5363%203.75349%201.5416%206.3086%200%202.77156-1.1192%205.12607-3.3576%207.05825-2.2172%201.93217-5.1947%202.89826-8.9271%202.90354-3.2783%200-6.0763-.77604-8.3991-2.32283m30.4924-35.25956h5.0417v36.94889h-5.0417zm29.0249%204.54008v32.40881h-5.0416v-32.40881h-11.7567v-4.54008h29.0829v4.54008zm24.1522%200v10.26798h12.2054v4.28669h-12.2054v13.31406h16.7455v4.54008h-21.7924V241.9495h22.0669v4.54008zM64.84929%20211.18252c48.61584-13.77863%2099.91351-21.14835%20152.93218-21.14835%2053.21396%200%20104.70176%207.42779%20153.47066%2021.30144l-1.2934%204.5612c-48.3572-13.75751-99.4067-21.12194-152.17726-21.12194-52.5805%200-103.44527%207.30636-151.63879%2020.96885zm171.30368-28.94568h-5.28444V0h5.28444zm-15.84806%200h-5.27916V0h5.27916zm-15.84806%200h-5.28444V0h5.28444zm-15.84278%200h-5.28444V52.82335h5.28444zm-15.84806%200h-5.27916V52.82335h5.27916zm95.07782%200h-5.2845V29.05126h5.2845z%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fsvg%3E" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <h1>World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```