# Explanation of <script type = "text/template"> ... </script>

Tags: javascript, html, templates

I just stumbled upon something I've never seen before. In the [source of Backbone.js's example TODO application](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/examples/todos/index.html#L52) ([Backbone TODO Example](http://backbonejs.org/examples/todos/index.html)) they had their templates inside a `<script type="text/template"></script>`, which contained code that looks like something out of `PHP` but with `JavaScript` tags.

Can someone explain this to me? Is this legit?

Comment: Great question and answer.  I just ran across this trick in the new YUI App Framework code: http://new.yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/app/app-todo.html

Comment: What about `type="text/tcl"` which I saw [in the W3C doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.3)? How to use it? (Should I ask another question?)

Comment: @L01man yes, you should ask another question.

Comment: mjhm's YUI link now at: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/app/app-todo.html

Answer (score 442, accepted):

Those script tags are a common way to implement templating functionality (like in PHP) but on the client side.

By setting the type to "text/template", it's not a script that the browser can understand, and so the browser will simply ignore it. This allows you to put anything in there, which can then be extracted later and used by a templating library to generate HTML snippets.

Backbone doesn't force you to use any particular templating library - there are quite a few out there: [Mustache](http://github.com/janl/mustache.js), [Haml](http://github.com/creationix/haml-js), [Eco](http://github.com/sstephenson/eco),[Google Closure template](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/), and so on (the one used in the example you linked to is [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template)). These will use their own syntax for you to write within those script tags.

Comment: @Matt, exactly that. At the same time it's easy to retrieve the full text again using `.innerHTML`, hence it's common practice now among templating engines.

Comment: Well isn't that just fantastic news! I've been looking for a solution like this.. Thanks for your response and follow-up!

Comment: hi, different Matt here.  Would <script type="text/template"> pass an html verification test?

Comment: it does not work when there is `</script>` in your text inside text/template

Comment: FYI, "text/template" is not a valid media type according to the IANA http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text

Comment: Looking forward to `<template />` tag. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/ & http://caniuse.com/#search=template

Comment: The template must be inline within the HTML; it is not possible to access the contents of a script linked with the `src` attribute. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035839/how-to-outsource-a-template-js-to-a-different-file-when-using-handlebars-js

Comment: Hello from the future. `<template>` is here, but sites are still using this technique, such as reddit.com. :F

Comment: @VictorZamanian Hello from further in the future, if you're using a templating framework that has custom indicators for variables the `template` tag will probably fail because the browser tries to parse it into a `DocumentFragment` :/

Answer (score 124):

It's legit and very handy!

Try this:

```
<script id="hello" type="text/template">
  Hello world
</script>
<script>
  alert($('#hello').html());
</script>
```

Several Javascript templating libraries use this technique. [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/) is a good example.

Comment: How would you do this alert in raw javascript with jquery?

Comment: @tremor Do you mean in raw javascript without jquery? Something like: var el = document.getElementById('hello'); var html = el.textContent; alert(html); (you'll need to look further into processing script tags' text in IE)

Comment: @SgtPooki ya i meant without, thanks for the answer. What I'd really like to do is src that script to an external file and get it, but I've found that's not really possible.. so I'm diving into AJAX and socket.io now.

Comment: @tremor, I may not understand exactly what you're trying to do, but grabbing external files dynamically, to either run or parse as a template, is definitely possible. Check out requirejs.

Comment: @tremor If you want to pull external files dynamically, I'd rather use XHR than script tags. XHR also works with plain HTML responses... or anything else for that matter.

Comment: Oh my word, I've been looking for this.

Answer (score 30):

By setting script tag `type` other than `text/javascript`, browser will not execute the internal code of script tag. This is called micro template. This concept is widely used in Single page application(aka SPA).

```html
<script type="text/template">I am a Micro template. 
  I am going to make your web page faster.</script>
```

For micro template, type of the script tag is `text/template`. It is very well explained by Jquery creator John Resig http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/

Comment: Great resource you included. That link taught me a lot.

Answer (score 16):

`<script type = "text/template"> … </script>` is obsolete. Use `<template>` tag instead.

Comment: `<template>` tag still isn't supported by Internet Explorer as of IE 11.

Comment: In 5 years time use the <template> tag.

Comment: <script type = “text/template”> can hold anything, they are not parsed. On the other hand, <template> tags are parsed into a DOM, hence needs to valid HTML. Usually, this means that the first will be kept as intact template, while the second will strip away non-html-compliant parts and break the template. ...of course, it's only a problem if you use template engines like mustache or the like.

Comment: This is a part of WebComponents and we can already use it with polymer in all browsers, or natively with some browser.

Comment: if you use webcomponents.js template tag will work in all browsers that you may need to support since IE8 is not supported even by Microsoft
https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs

Comment: Do NOT use <template> tag, and don't make your decision based on something else being "obsolete". This is not the Milan Fashion Week, if something is working and technically appropriate, it can be used :) Now for real: <template> tag is still unsupported in IE and Opera Mini (according to CanIUse), and <script> tag will hold exactly what you give it, as opposed to a hidden div or any other tag that might lose your whitespaces or comments.

Comment: 2 years since the answer posted, 
IE11 itself is an obsolete technology, and Microsoft has move to Edge instead, which support `<template>`. Most major desktop browser has support this `<template>` tag. I strongly recommend using it as of now. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template#Browser_compatibility

Comment: if you would like to use the template tag you can create the tag for IE browsers: 

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var isIE = !!window.ActiveXObject;
if(isIE){
 document.createElement("template");
}
</script>
```

Comment: After 5 years, you can't still use `<template>`. IE11 IS STILL ALIVE.

Comment: Modern WordPress plugins such as Elementor still use `<script type="text/html">` or `<script type="text/template">`.

Answer (score 14):

To add to Box9's answer:

Backbone.js is dependent on underscore.js, which itself implements John Resig's original microtemplates.

If you decide to use Backbone.js with Rails, be sure to check out the Jammit gem. It provides a very clean way to manage asset packaging for templates. 
http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit/#jst

By default Jammit also uses JResig's microtemplates, but it also allows you to replace the templating engine.

Comment: To add, DocumentCloud, which provides Jammit, is the same company that developed Backbone and Underscore.

Answer (score 13):

It's a way of adding text to HTML without it being rendered or normalized.

It's no different than adding it like:

```html
<textarea style="display:none"><span>{{name}}</span></textarea>
```

Comment: It is different, a textarea will still insert those elements into the DOM and fetch any external assets (like images) requested.  A script tag will not.

Comment: @LocalPCGuy thats not true, including `<img src="image.jpg">` inside a textarea will not cause the browser to fetch `image.jpg`, the browser knows that the content inside a textarea is not meant to be rendered.

Comment: @vikki woops, you are correct, textarea may be one of the few elements that would be a viable replacement for script tag templating.

Comment: @LocalPCGuy yeah I think those two can be used interchangebly. If your template has the line `</script>` you can't use it inside a script tag, so you can use the textarea then, and vice versa.

Comment: Yup... Before template tag and before script type=text/template, we all did it with textarea, I believe.  It's the same thing with iframes when we had no ajax.

Comment: However something like an `<input type="hidden" value="4458">` would not care about being hidden via `display:none`, and could still mess up your submitted form.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery Templates is an example of something that uses this method to store HTML that will not be rendered directly (that’s the whole point) inside other HTML:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/

Comment: jQuery.template is abandoned, and followed up by http://www.jsviews.com/#jsrender