# Can i use this coding in looping statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code like this

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<hr id="line1" color="#0f0" size="2" width="50px">
<div id="div2" ></div><br>
<hr id="line2" color="#0f0" size="2" width="50px" style="display:none;" >
<div id="div3" ></div><br>
<hr id="line3" color="#0f0" size="2" width="3.5%" style="display:none;" >
<div id="div4" ></div><br>
<hr id="line4" color="#0f0" size="2" width="3.5%" style="display:none;" >
<div id="div5" ></div><br>
<hr id="line5" color="#0f0" size="2" width="3.5%" style="display:none;">
```

Can i use this coding in any looping statement with the uses of script or jquery.

Comment: Yes you can and let's wait and hear for `what have you tried` :)

Comment: What exactly do you want to loop through?  The `div`s?  What is the criteria for determining what should be included, i.e., everything with id of the format `div#`?

Comment: what do you want to do in the loop? what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can loop through the divs for example this way:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    $("#div"+i).some_method();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Use a HTML template.

Try [JQuery Tmpl](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/)

[KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) talks about Templates in detail on their website.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912586/explanation-of-script-type-text-template-script) also mentions templates and several ways of using them.

Here's how it looks in a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/YYfmu/

Answer (score 1):

[working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/JCMAJ/)

you can loop using `div hr` if you have any thing in the div

or use `hr` to loop

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

```
for(var i =1; i<= 5; i++)
{
$('#target').append('<div id="div'+ i +'" </div><br>')
$('#target').append('<hr id=line'+i+'" color="#0f0" size="2" width="50px" style="display:none;">')
}
```

Comment: not at all what I thought you were going for, though apparently some others here understood it.