# How to outsource a template js to a different file when using Handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mvvm, handlebars.js

I have this template script

```
<script id="some-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
   {{#users}}
     {username}
     {email}
</script>
```

I want to out-source it to a file called "user_template.js" which will look like this:

```
   {{#users}}
     {username}
     {email}
```

and make in the main index.html this link:

```
<script id="some-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template" src="user_template.js"></script>
```

The problem is - **it doesn't work** - how do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ajax to load the template file.

With jQuery:

```
$.get("user_template.js", function(template_text){
    var template = Handlebars.compile(template_text);
    // more things
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use **RequireJS** for this. Lovely to work with modules and there is also a plugin that is called **text** that works beautifully with templates.

If it sounds interesting, here's some links:

http://requirejs.org/

http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#text -- The text plugin

RequireJS is only suitable if you want to use modules though, if not Alon's answer is better.