# access to contents of script tag with src attribute (template including)

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to outsource a template js to a different file when using Handlebars.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035839/how-to-outsource-a-template-js-to-a-different-file-when-using-handlebars-js)

I'm using handlebears. They recommend to include templates in documents body like this:

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
     template content
</script>
```

I want to use template contents through src attribute and store my templates (mass of) in separate files.

```
<script src="/path/to/my.template" id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template"></script>
```

Question is how to access co contents of it?

```
$('script#entry-template').html() //returns ""
$('script#entry-template').text() //returns ""
```

Comment: Could you just do an ajax get to retrieve the contents of the file?

Comment: Thanx. Didn't find it by search

Comment: The idea is to use browser standart mechanism. When it meets script tag with src attribute it loads it. Or not? I've tested it by doing $('head').append('<script src="/path/to"></script') and seen XMLHttpRequest. Does jquery executed it?

Comment: Any other type than "text/javascript" will escape <script> tag content

Comment: Side comment: id is not a regular attribute of script tags, I am very surprised to see it used in Handlebars.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to get the value of the `src` attribute, then request the URI with XMLHttpRequest … at which point you are better off not using a `<script type="not-js">` at all.

Browsers don't automatically download unknown script types, and they don't make scripts accessible programatically to JS. You can access *inline* scripts as they are part of the DOM, external scripts are not.