# what does browser do when it encounters <script type= text/template ..>

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Explanation of <script type = “text/template”> … </script>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912586/explanation-of-script-type-text-template-script)

After starting learning backbone.js I am wondering what exactly browser does when it encounters

```
<script type= text/template>
 ...
</script>
```

http://bytes.com/topic/html-css/answers/542484-browser-behavior-unknown-tags-attributes people are explaining what happens if it sees unknown tab, but in this case the tag is known and the browser knows what to do with it, the problem is with type.

So the questions are:

- does it try to execute it?
- is it ignoring it?

Why exactly do we need `<script type= text/template>...</script>`, why just we can not use `<div style="display:none"> ... </div>`?

Comment: The best place to start for information on HTML elements is the HTML specification, google for "site:w3.org html the-element-you-want", limiting the search to w3.org avoids garbage like w3fools.com. Read about `<script>`: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/script.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser simply ignores such tags.
It's useful to put templates inside such tags, because you don't need to encode HTML symbols like `<`, `>`, `&` for example:

```
<script type="text/template">
    <% for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { %>
        // do something
    <% } %>
</script>
```

Inside the hidden div you should write something like this:

```
<script type="text/template">
    &lt;% for(var i = 0; i &lt; 10; i++) { %&gt;
        // do something
    &lt;% } %&gt;
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The browser ignores it -- it cannot try and execute the script, since it doesn't recognize the type.

And you can't use a div, because the template is often not valid HTML (eg, the underscore templating syntax `<%= modelproperty %>`.