# How can I correctly store a HTML template within a HTML page?

Tags: javascript, mustache

I have some small template strings, which will be rendered through Mustache.js on the same page.I need not create seperate html files for templates.

Options for storing the templates :

1. Storing in javascript variables :  Hackish multiline strings, lots of escaping of quotes.
2. Storing as innerHTML of hidden divs.

I tried method#2, but it does not seem to work correctly.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/RHwnq/2/

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id='templates' class='hide' align="">
         <div id='tableTemplate'>
            <table class="table">
                 {{#name_list}}
                  <tr><td> {{name}} </td></tr>
                {{/name_list}}
            </table>
         </div>
</div>

<script>
 var template = $('#tableTemplate').html();
 console.log(template);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This logs :

```
{{#name_list}}
  {{name}} 
{{/name_list}}
<table class="table"><tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Instead of :

```
  <table class="table">
                     {{#name_list}}
                      <tr><td> {{name}} </td></tr>
                    {{/name_list}}
  </table>
```

This might be to due to some markup correction by the browser.
What are other good tricks to store HTML templates within an HTML page ?

Comment: What about not storing them in the same file, but loading them via AJAX?

Comment: @feeela no, I do not want to make ajax calls to load 2-3 small strings,I intend to store them in the same page.

Comment: In some tutorials related to backbone.js/underscore.js they stored the templates within <script type="text/template" id="template-id"></script> tags. Take a closer look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912586/explanation-of-script-type-text-template-script

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I store them in a script tag, so they don't get rendered, like this:

```
<script id="abc-template" type="text/html">
    <h1>{{name}}</h1>
</script>
```

You can then reference them like this:

```
var template = $('#abc-template').html();
var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
$('#abc-div').html(html);
```

Comment: Ha, same solution in a matter of seconds :)

Comment: FML saved me a whole day.

Answer (score 6):

Using `<script>` tags works great for this:

```
<script id="tableTemplate" type="text/html">
  <table class="table">
    {{#name_list}}
    <tr><td> {{name}} </td></tr>
    {{/name_list}}
  </table>
</script>
```

It's actually a drop-in replacement, it will work with your `var template = $('#tableTemplate').html();`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your IDE, you may or may not get HTML syntax highlighting within `<script></script>` blocks. I use a `div` block as you did, but add

```
#templates {display: none;}
```

to the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use HTML "template" tag.

`<template id="tmp">Some HTML here</template>`

See this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/cityremade/xwLht8vc/