# Use <script type="text/template">, <script type="text/tcl"> or <template> for client side HTML templates?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, client-side

I know, there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912586/explanation-of-script-type-text-template-script) available - however, this was 3 years ago, and the comment about `text/tcl` didn't seem to catch up in the discussion.

---

**Do you know which version is to prefer when implementing client side templates:**

`<script type="text/template">` or `<script type="text/tcl">` or even `<template>`?

- I heard that some security software may filter out certain `<script>` tags which do not match a common standard, so `text/template` could probably be filtered out by some proxy or antivirus software due to security reasons?
- Is there any disadvantage in using `text/tcl`?
- Is it save to use `<template>` when creating the element first with `document.createElement("template")` for older browsers (IE)?

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explanation of <script type = "text/template"> ... </script>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912586/explanation-of-script-type-text-template-script)

Comment: Back in the early days of the web, TCL was competing with JavaScript and VBScript as a web scripting language. The W3C probably used it as an example as JavaScript is outside the W3C's remit (ECMA publishes the ECMAScript/JavaScript standards and specifications, not the W3C).

Comment: Not a duplicate. OP specifically linked to the question and said how it's different.

Comment: @SecondRikudo: I think the OP edited the question to address the comment during the grace period, but I might be mistaken.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy could be either way, it doesn't change the fact that right now, it's not a duplicate :)

Comment: I appreciate you declaring this question NOT as a duplicate - however, if you also would have an actual answer to the question, this would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I've not heard of security software attacking specific `type`s of `<script>`; all my experience has been with "security" software that mangled any `<script>` they saw. Some research doesn't turn anything further up, but they may have targeted things like VBScript during the bad old IE6-COM exploit days.
2. `text/tcl` means [the Tcl language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl), an old W3C choice for a web scripting language that wasn't JavaScript. (There is a long story behind this which explains things like why the DOM is so terrible.)

   Work *was* done on implementing it, but I cannot find any browser that accomplished this. [There is a Tcl browser plugin](http://www.tcl.tk/software/plugin/), but its demos use `application/x-tcl`, so probably nothing will happen even for that one guy running a decade-old browser with inadvisable plugin choices.

   The only effect other than the browser ignoring it I **do** know is that old Internet Explorer does a registry lookup for handlers of unknown `type` values on `<script>`. (This came up during HTML5's new `<script type="module">`, but I can't dig up the right mailing list/GitHub issue/chat log/wherever the WHATWG discovered that.) They decided it was ignorable (with the Edge team's blessing).
3. It's relatively safe, but beware that markup inside the shivved `<template>` will still execute; `src` attributes will load ([even if they're empty](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/11/30/empty-image-src-can-destroy-your-site/)), `<script>`s will run, `<style>`s will style, etc.