# Select element in HTML document not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm trying to use the Select2 library. But I haven't been able to get anything to show up. Even when I tried this simple example, it didn't work. The HTML file, CSS file and JS file are all in the same folder.

When I load this the browser is totally blank.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="select2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="controls-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(".example-basic-multiple").select2();
                <select class="example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">
                    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                </select>
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with jQuery or the select2 library but shouldn't you have your `<select>` elements outside of the `<script>` tags?

Comment: What are the follow up questions?

Comment: They were answered, I forgot to remove that from the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the `<select>` *outside* of the script tag, preferably in the `<head>`, after linking to the JS libraries :

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title>title</title>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <link href="select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <script src="select2.js"></script>
            <script> 
                $(function() {//Waits until the page is fully loaded before running code
                $(".example-basic-multiple").select2();
                });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="controls-group">
                <div class="controls">                        
                    <select class="example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">
                        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: How about putting the HTML before the script that is supposed to access it?

Comment: @ErikE edited it, just said to put it in the head, its easiest :D

Comment: This was the fix. I was following the examples at https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/select2-ng/docs/examples.html  and they the select tags inside the script tags.

Comment: Like @ErikE said though, its only working for me if I put the script after the select tag. Could someone help me understand that? And also why in the link I provided they have it setup differently and its still working for them?

Comment: @BrentConnor I created [a pull request for the author to fix his code](https://github.com/select2/select2/pull/3066).

Comment: @BrentConnor As the browser parses the DOM, it *runs* any script elements it finds *as it's parsing*. This means that when the script element is parsed, and run, if the `select` element comes later in the DOM, there *is* no `select` element yet to operate on.

Comment: @ErikE I think in the docs he said he doesn't respond to pull requests about the docs.

Comment: @BrentConnor Not sure where we mention not accepting docs PRs, but it should say _the exact opposite_.

Comment: @ErikE The browser will only parse `<script>` tags with a `type` set to `text/javascript` automatically, anything else will be ignored. You can look at other libraries which use `<script>` tags for templating to confirm that, [like Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

Comment: @KevinBrown https://github.com/select2/select2/tree/select2-ng/docs "Pull requests will usually be ignored, documentation fixes should be made in the source repository. We may accept pull requests if they match the source docs directory, but for the most part pull requests will be closed on sight."

Comment: @BrentConnor Ah, my bad. That's intended for the [docs repo](https://github.com/select2/select2.github.io) and I can clarify it to make that more obvious.

Comment: @KevinBrown The requirement for `type="text/javascript"` *used* to be true, but it's not any more. Please try it out, yourself!

Comment: @ErikE [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4912586/359284) might be a useful read. Let's pull up a chat room if there is going to be further discussion, so we don't clutter these comments.

Comment: Note for future readers. `<script>` tags with NO type at all will be treated as `text/javascript`. This is what I was thinking of when I misunderstood Kevin and answered above. `<script>window.alert('hello');</script>` will indeed be parsed and run by the browser.

Comment: @BrentConnor to fix your problem with the code only working if placed after, see my updated answer