# Using Javascript's eval() on HTML Text

Tags: javascript, html, eval

I am toying around with some basic constructs in HTML and Javascript (i.e., I am a HTML/Javascript n00b), and there is a feature I simply cannot seem to implement properly. In a nutshell, I'd like to grab text from the body of an HTML page and evaluate it using Javascript (either eval() or new Function()). To see that my use of eval() is right, I first tried the following code, which works as expected (and displays the value 5):

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    eval("var t = function () { if (5>0) return 5; }();");
    document.body.innerHTML = t;
}
</script>
```

However, when I then attempt to achieve my goal of grabbing the "code" from the HTML and running it, this seems to fail for me. Here's a piece of code that doesn't work (I've tried many variations of this):

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myP").innerHTML;
    eval("var e = " + x + ";");
    document.body.innerHTML = e();
}
</script>

<body>
    <p id="myP">function () { if (5>1) { return 5; } } </p>
</body>
```

I tested that the variable `x` does in fact contain the desired "code" from the body. But for some reason, the above will just not work correctly; it will just display the body and ignore the `eval` and the statement after it updating the innerHTML.

What's stranger is that when I try code that is "more complex", it works fine, such as:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myP").innerHTML;
    eval("var e = " + x + ";");
    document.body.innerHTML = e();
}
</script>

<body>
    <p id="myP">function () { var a = []; var b = [1,2,3]; for (var i in b) { a.push([b[i],'q']); } return a; } </p>
</body>
```

It seems really weird to me that this example should work but not the previous one; does eval() hate if-statements? Am I missing some subtle aspect of eval()? Am I missing some super-basic Javascript syntax? Any help is appreciated, both in getting the above particular instance to work, as well as advice for how to implement what I am trying to do generally, i.e. to pass *any* code from HTML to eval().

**NOTE:** If possible, please avoid any comments/answers about how eval() is "evil" or is a major security issue, or any such remarks. I am aware of these concerns. My issue is within the context of a personal project and has no chance of being publicly deployed or used unsafely etc.

Comment: What is the `e()` you are trying to execute? Trying doing just `document.body.innerHTML = e;`

Comment: @khalid13 its in the statement executed by the eval(); its assigned a function, hence the e(). it executes fine in my 3rd code example...

Comment: It's probably an encoding issue, like certain characters being converted to their HTML Entity versions.

Comment: To avoid the problem that James described you can enclose in a template. See this post for more information: [Explanation of <script type = “text/template”>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912586/explanation-of-script-type-text-template-script)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is related to the DOM, rather than JavaScript. You're asking for the `innerHTML` of a node. If you have a look at what you end up with the problem becomes clear:

```
var x = document.getElementById("myP").innerHTML;
console.log(x); // "function () { if (5&gt;1) { return 5; } }"
```

The browser has converted the `>` character into an HTML entity. What you need is the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) of the node:

```
var x = document.getElementById("myP").textContent;
console.log(x); // "function () { if (5>1) { return 5; } }"
```

Here's a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/bn4rpcf6/).

Comment: out of curiosity, I notice you use both "innerText" and "textContent"; would you mind briefly commenting on the difference?

Comment: @Coffee_Table sorry, it should have been `textContent`. `innerText` was introduced in Internet Explorer and AFAIK isn't part of a standard. Most browsers will support it but `textContent` is preferable for reasons discussed in the linked `textContent` page.