# HTML <script type=template> official?

Tags: html, standards

Beside the fact that there is a [template tag in HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template), I'm wondering if this type of script tag `<script type="text/template">` is conform with the HTML standards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-type):

> The script element allows authors to include dynamic script and **data blocks** in their documents.

So including a template there is fine.

`text/template`, however, is not [a registered MIME type](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) so `text/x-template` would be more appropriate (`x-` is the traditional prefix for experimental MIME types).

Comment: I see, so then there is the question if "text/template" is included in RFC 723: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231 does not list it.

Comment: RFC 7231 has nothing to do with it. That's the HTTP spec. IANA is responsible for maintaining the MIME type registry.

Comment: Conclusion: script with attribute type="text/template" is not covered by W3C specs.

Comment: … because specific values for that attribute are explicitly not the W3C's responsibility (and are the IANA's instead)

Comment: That's complicated... I never really understood those dependencies. (And what browsers actually DO is a totally different thing ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

its an old question but it was asked a few years ago: [Explanation of <script type = "text/template"> ... </script>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912586/explanation-of-script-type-text-template-script)

by the looks of it it isn't official. Just a way for you to incorperate other code

Comment: Yes, I saw that question. But understand it as the questioner was asking for explanation and not specifically about a valid specification.