# Html 'Ghost' Element

Tags: templates, dom, element, shadow, ghost

Is there any HTML element which acts just as a shadow in the DOM?
I am using a templating system and I don't want the template/shadow element to affect my DOM. Example...

```
<div class='container'>
  <shadow>
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
  </shadow>
</div>
```

I want to have just the div and the spans in the DOM, with the template/shadow element acting as a ghost and not affecting structure and giving direct relation between the div and the span.

Comment: all i could find is the `inert=inert` attribute .. http://www.html.am/tags/html-div-tag.cfm ... but it does not seem to be working...

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/4912586/124222 maybe that is what you were looking for. PS: If you found your solution please answer your own question and mark it as the correct answer.