# Marionette 3 templates work inline, but not when included in a separate file

Tags: javascript, templates, inline, marionette

I've been able to get my Marionette 3 templates to work when they are inline.  When I include the template in an .html file I get a NoTemplateError when rendering the view.  I've seen examples that use TemplateCache and require, but I don't understand why I can't just include the template .html file in the body and have it work.

The main source file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">

<head>
    <title>Gmail API Quickstart</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
</head>

<body>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="underscore_1_8_3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="backbone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="backbone.radio.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="backbone.marionette_3_2_0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="mycss.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="messageDetails.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

// This template works

```
<script type="x-template/underscore" id="mailItem-template">
    <div id="mailItem" class="col-md-12">
            <img src="trash_recyclebin_empty_closed.png" align = "top" width="18" height="18"/>
            <input type="checkbox" style="padding: 10;"/>
    </div>
</script>
```

// If I comment out the above template and put the template in .html file it  doesn't work in the view.  I've tried

```
<link href="mailItem.tmpl.html" type="text/html"/>
```

// I've also tried this, but I get an Syntax error

```
<script src="mailItem.tmpl.html" type="text/javascript"/>
```

// View that uses the template

```
<script src="MessageDetailsView.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because using the `<script>` tag isn't going to load it.  Essentially if a `<script>` tag isn't javascript the browser will leave it alone.. this is handy since you can grab it later to use it as a template, but the browser isn't ever going to load the external template.

What you *could* do is make your external template a javascript.

```
var myTemplate = _.('My template text');
```

then you should be able to load that via a  tag an expect `myTemplate` to be available globally.

But your best options is most likely to use a build tool like webpack to precompile and import your templates as javascript into your script directly.

More info:
[Explanation of <script type = "text/template"> ... </script>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912586/explanation-of-script-type-text-template-script)