# Internet Explorer 11 removes script tags in body

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11, script-tag

I currently have a peculiar problem with the IE11; it seems like it removes all my `script` tags in the `body` tag.

For instance I receive the following HTML from the server:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="somehost.com/somescript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <!--some content here-->
</div>
<div>
    <!--some content here-->
</div>
<script type="text/template" class="someclass">
    <div>
        <!--some dynamic content here-->
    </div>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The rendered result:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="somehost.com/somescript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <!--some content here-->
</div>
<div>
    <!--some content here-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My use-case is the following:
I have an image with clickable areas. Each area opens a lightbox on click, which has its html provided from `script` tags in the body since it is dynamic content from the server. I am using jquery to query the corresponding `script` tag with the proper html. It works properly in Firefox and Chrome, only the IE11 is giving me a headache by removing the `script` tags.

What am I missing? Why is IE11 removing script tags from the body? Is there a security setting to configure this behavior?

Comment: How exactly are you checking this "rendered result"?

Comment: I am checking with the dom inspector

Comment: i would suggest that you provide more information on what you are using to render the dynamic content/templates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explanation of <script type = "text/template"> ... </script>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912586/explanation-of-script-type-text-template-script)

Comment: How is this a duplicate? He isn't asking for the explaination of the <script> type?