# use asp.net razor html helper with innerHTML

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I want to provide html helper to innerHTML . But can not able to do so.Here is my code.How to solve this

```
element.innerHTML = '@Html.DropDownList("TopTags", null, new { @onchange = "ChangeCallback(this.value);" })'
```

Comment: I've updated my answer. My original code produced quotes within the quotes which is just wrong. This should now be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script id="anything" type="text/template">
        @Html.DropDownList("TopTags", null, new { @onchange = "ChangeCallback(this.value);" })
</script>
<script>
     ....
     element.innerHTML=document.getElementById("anything").innerHTML;
</script>
```

Comment: Anything inside `<script type="text/template">` [will be ignored by the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4912608/6682181), so this JavaScript code will never be executed. I don't think that's gonna help the OP.

Comment: @haindl I think now it can be help

Comment: That's a bit better but there's still one major issue: The OP didn't state that he uses jQuery. The tags only specify ASP.NET MVC. If the OP doesn't use jQuery then he surely won't change his application architecture just to make one simple call that can be solved very simple without jQuery.

Comment: Remove jquery from my answer

Comment: Excuse me, but have you even tried your own code? I'm getting the JavaScript error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null`. That's because `<script id="anything" type="text/template">` has to be defined [before the getElementById call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8716680/6682181). So you have to swap your `<script>` blocks to make it work.

Comment: @haindl already try my code. But writing here make mistake. I wrote innerHtml instead of innerHTML

Comment: Yes, `innerHtml ` instead of `innerHTML` was another error. But you still need to change the order of your `<script>` blocks. If you don't, then `document.getElementById("anything")` won't find the element because it can only find elements that are defined before the call.

Comment: You are right change my blocks. Next time I coppy paste from my editor. No write again here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.DropDownList()` will generate multiple lines of HTML code. You need to encode this output so that JavaScript can understand it.

The following should do the trick:

```
element.innerHTML = '@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Html.DropDownList("TopTags", null, new { @onchange = "ChangeCallback(this.value);" }).ToHtmlString().Replace("\"", "'"))';
```