# What difference between tag <template> and script type = 'text/template'?

Tags: javascript, templates

I need to put some HTML in JS. I saw two ways to do it: the `<template>`-tag and `<script type = 'text/template'>`, but I don't understand the difference/
what's the difference between `<template>`-tag and `<script type = 'text/template'>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<template>` is used to define reusable snippets of HTML that Javascript can use. You would define it with an id, and then use it.

`<script type='text/template'>` escapes the normal HTML processor because `text/template` is not a valid MIME type. Thus is outputs as plain-text. Learn more here: **[Explanation of <script type = "text/template"> ... </script>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912586/explanation-of-script-type-text-template-script)**

EDIT:

`text/html` indicates that the HTML processor should be applied, formatting all HTML tags and the like.

Comment: and what defference beetwen "text/html" and "text/template"?