# Which Javascript framework is being used in this example code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, android-webview

This is a piece of code found in a webview directory in an Android project.

```
    <script id="table" type="text/template">
      <table>
        {% _.each(data.rows, function(row) { %}
            <tr>
                {% if (row.length == 1) { %}
                    <td style="text-align: center" colspan="{{data.maxRowLength}}">
                        {{row[0]}}
                    </td>
                {% } else { %}
                    {% _.each(row, function(cell) { %}
                        <td>{{ cell }}</td>
                    {% }) %}
                {% } %}
            </tr>
        {% }) %}
    </table>
    <br>
   </script>
```

Comment: That doesn't look like javascript.  It might be a js templating enginer (given `<script text/template`) or it might be php or a python framework like django.

Comment: Hey everyone, I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912586/explanation-of-script-type-text-template-script) solves it. Someone commented with the link but then deleted their comment.

Answer (score 0):

looks like Django templating(python framework) engine but this is a guess
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be similar to Jinja Templating - https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/