# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style') at handleClick

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I want to change my target div variable's `display` property from `none` to `block`.

```js
const userListEl = document.getElementById('user-list').innerHTML;
const template = Handlebars.compile(userListEl);
const targetDiv = document.getElementById("userDetail");


fetch("https://5dc588200bbd050014fb8ae1.mockapi.io/assessment")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        var userData = template({ usersList: data })
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = userData;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })

 this is my function

const hanldeClick =  () => {
    if (targetDiv.style.display === "none") {
        targetDiv.style.display = "block";
        
    } else {
        targetDiv.style.display = "none";
    }
 
};
```

```css
#userDetail {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Exercise 1</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="test"></div>
    <script id="user-list" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <ul class="people_list"> {{#each usersList}} 
            <li>                
                <p class="">{{name}}</p>
                <img src={{avatar}} alt={{name}}>
                <div id="userDetail">
                    <p>Id: {{id}}</p>
                     <p>Created at: {{createdAt}}</p>
                 </div>
                <button onclick="hanldeClick()"> Detail </button>
            </li>
             {{/each}} 
            </ul>
          
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js" defer></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handlebars@latest/dist/handlebars.js"></script>

</body>
```

I want to change the display value `none` to `block` in an onclick handler, but when the button is clicked I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

`targetDiv` is `null` when you click the "Detail" button and trigger the `handleClick` function because there is *no* DOM element with the id `userDetail` when you invoke `document.getElementById("userDetail");`.

To verify this, you could log the value of `targetDiv` immediately after your assignment:

```
const targetDiv = document.getElementById("userDetail");
console.log(targetDiv); // null
```

Why is `<div id="userDetail">` not a DOM element?

Because it is a part of a template within a `script` tag. The `type="text/x-handlebars-template"` attribute you have added to your script block is basically telling the browser to ignore what it contains. This is what allows you to add arbitrary content, like the mustaches understood by the Handlebars library. For more on this: see [Explanation of <script type = "text/template"> ... </script>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4912586/3397771)

In order for your code to reference the DOM element with id `userDetail`, you will need to get it from the DOM *after* you have injected your template-rendered HTML into document - ie., *after* you set the `innerHTML` of `#test` to `userData`:

```
let targetDiv = null;

fetch("https://5dc588200bbd050014fb8ae1.mockapi.io/assessment")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        var userData = template({ usersList: data })
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = userData;
        targetDiv = document.getElementById("userDetail");
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/o4q7na56/) for your reference.

Additionally, even with this fix, I think you are going to find that your code does not work as you intend. It looks like you want `handleClick` to toggle a sibling `<div>` - and that this should be the effect for *each* `<li>` in your `<ul>`. However, your `document.getElementById("userDetail")` will return only the *first* element with id `userDetail`, so no matter which "Detail" `<button>` is clicked, only the first `<li>`'s detail will be toggled. You will need to find a way to specify to your handler *which* detail to toggle.