# Parse error for Handlebars partial: {{> interpreted as {{&gt;

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, html-entities, parse-error

I'm following this guide to use partials in my web project: https://handlebarsjs.com/examples/partials/basic.html

In the .html file, I was using this just fine (using Tailwind CSS):

```
{{#each pages}}
<li class="font-sans text-base leading-none block text-right border-t-2 border-icon-header-base/40 first-of-type:border-0 hover:bg-icon-header-base/40 hover:border-background-menu-dropdown">
   <a href="pages/{{ fileName }}" class="block pr-4 leading-[45px] align-middle text-text-header-base hover:text-text-header-hover">{{ name }}</a>
</li>
{{/each}}
```

Then I tried to make it a partial.

Script:

```
Handlebars.registerPartial('mobileDropBullet','<li class="block font-sans text-lg leading-none last-of-type:pb-1 border-t-2 border-icon-header-base/40"><a href="pages/{{ fileName }}" class="text-text-header-base block py-3.5 pl-8">{{ name }}</a></li>');
```

New HTML:

```
{{#each pages}}
   {{> mobileDropBullet fileName=fileName name=name}}
{{/each}}
```

**But now in the Console I get this error:**

```
Uncaught Error: Parse error on line 4:
...                 {{&gt; mobileDropBullet
-----------------------^
Expecting 'ID', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'UNDEFINED', 'NULL', 'DATA', got 'INVALID'
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It looks like your helper call is being HTML-escaped by whatever is rendering it. In what type of file is your Handlebars template?

Comment: It's a small site, so my Handlebars template is just in index.js

Comment: Can you explain more about how this is working? Handlebars templates are not valid JavaScript, so the templates cannot be in a `.js` file you load on the client. Is `index.js` processed on a Node server - something like Express.js?

Comment: I see, I did not realize this about Handlebars. index.js is just a regular .js file that I created to run the scripts for my .html files. It's not using any sort of processing. Would you recommend I use Express.js? What is most common, for Handlebars?

Comment: I would put the Handlebars templates in `<script type="text/template">` tags. The `type="text/template"` part is telling the browser that what's inside is not JavaScript and should not be parsed as such. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4912586/3397771. However, the error you have shared in your post indicates that Handlebars is working just fine (ie., it is correctly detecting a syntax error in your template), so it seems there is a piece of this puzzle that I do not understand.

Comment: Thank you @76484 the <script> tags stopped the error!

Comment: I am happy that you have got it working! I am little unsatisfied because I never fully understood what the original problem was. But that's OK.