# I want to add a file to the tag <input type"file"> but I can't

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<script id="TEMPLATE_GROUP_INFO_STRUCTURE" type="text/template"><button type="button" 
  class="MdBtn01Close02"><%= COMMON_CLOSE %></button>
    <h1 class="MdHide"><%= BUDDY_GROUP_EDIT %></h1>
      <div class="MdBox04">
        <div class="MdCMN09ImgEdit">
          <input type="file" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg" 
    class="mdCMN09ImgInput" style="background-image: url({{thumbnailImage}})" data- 
    picture-path="{{groupInfo.picturePath}}"
                   title="<%= BUDDY_GROUP_EDIT %>">
            </div>
        
        </div>
</script>
```

I want to add a file to the tag <input type"file"> but I can't

```
img = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@class="mdCMN09ImgInput"]')
img.send_keys('C:\\Users\\MyPc\\Desktop\\Ufazoom\\ban6 copy.png')
```

This is what I did. I got the Error NoSuchElementException.

Comment: Element not found on the page, try adding time to load it. `img =  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By`

Comment: This method didn't work.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site? do you need more information.

Comment: It's just the template text, which, let's say, on a button click, is converted to html, so it's not identified by selenium. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912586/explanation-of-script-type-text-template-script.

Comment: We need to see the link to the page you working on. there may be several issuey why your code not working

Comment: It is an extension google chrome app plication Line.