# Direct preloaded HTML content in iframe rather than src

Tags: html

I have HTML content (mostly e-mails) that I would like to display in an archive. Seeing as some of these records contain their own styles, images, and headers, they need to be displayed independently and confined to its container so as not to interfere with the page displaying it. I immediately thought of an iframe.

I have two ways I can do this, both are somewhat indirect. 1) I can draw an iframe that points to about:blank and use Javascript to draw the content into the iframe after the page loads. 2) I can create a secondary PHP page that returns only the content of the e-mail and point the iframe to it as the src attribute. These solutions are simple enough, but I was wondering if there is a more direct way.

I found solutions like these, but they suggest using options 1 or 2 above. The point of this question is: "Is there a more direct way to preload HTML content directly into an iframe than to rely on Javascript or a secondary page?"
[Html code as IFRAME source rather than a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102636/html-code-as-iframe-source-rather-than-a-url)
[Specifying content of an iframe instead of the src to a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199458/specifying-content-of-an-iframe-instead-of-the-src-to-a-page)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how much more "direct" you can get than to specify a page in the src attribute of the iframe.

You already link to the only answer that actually works in your question that does not include using a src page or using EMCAScript to draw the iframe content. Remember thought that data urls are still limited in the number of bytes of data they can display in most browsers because there are limits to the length of the data url itself.

I would really suggest that you use the src attribute with a seperate backend script as that will decouple and increase the maintainability of your code as you can develop the scripts responsible for the page itself seperatly from those that show the iframe content.