# parsing HTML with JSF in p:dialog

Tags: java, html, jsf, jsf-2, jakarta-mail

Hello i'm working in web application like GMAIL with JSF and javamail ,and i use p:dialog to preview the email : https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/1522023_568308536589120_1043722853_n.jpg

this is  the code  of the VUE :

```
<h:form id="form">  

    <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />  

    <p:dataTable id="cars" var="message" value="#{mailservice.emails}" >  
  <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":form:display" oncomplete="carDialog.show()" />
        <p:column headerText="From" style="width:24%">  
            <h:outputText value="#{message.from}" />  
        </p:column>  

        <p:column headerText="Subject" style="width:24%">  
            <h:outputText value="#{message.subject}" />  
        </p:column>  



        <p:column style="width:4%">  
                <p:commandButton id="selectButton" update=":form:display" oncomplete="carDialog.show()" icon="ui-icon-search" title="View">  
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{message}" target="#{mailservice.selectedMessage}" />  
            </p:commandButton>  
        </p:column>  

    </p:dataTable>  

    <p:dialog header="Car Detail" widgetVar="carDialog" resizable="false" id="carDlg"  
                showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode" modal="true">  

        <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4" style="margin:0 auto;">  

            <h:outputText value="Meassage :" />  
            <h:outputText value="#{mailservice.selectedMessage.text}" style="font-weight:bold"/>  

        </h:panelGrid>  

    </p:dialog>  

</h:form>
```

and this is the code of managed bean wich use to get the GMAIL email and store it in ArrayList :

```
public  ArrayList<Email> getEmails()
    { ArrayList<Email> emails=new ArrayList<Email>();
        try {
            Properties props = System.getProperties();
            props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imap");

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

            session.setDebug(true);
            Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
            System.out.println(store.getClass());
            store.connect("imap.gmail.com", Util.getEmail(), Util.getEmailPassword());
            System.out.println(store);

            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
            Message messages[] = inbox.getMessages();
            int nb = messages.length;
            int max;
            if(nb>=3)
                max=3;
            else
                max=nb;
            for(int i = nb-1 ;i>=nb-max;i--) {
                Message message = messages[i];
            emails.add(new Email(message.getFrom()[0].toString(), message.getSubject(), message.getContent().toString()));
            }
            inbox.close(true);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MailService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
            return emails;
    }
```

the problem is the html email shows the code html of the email like this :

https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/1522023_568308536589120_1043722853_n.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a normal behaviour, the `h:outputText` is by default escaping HTML tags.

You will have to replace

```
<h:outputText value="#{mailservice.selectedMessage.text}" style="font-weight:bold"/>
```

with

```
<h:outputText value="#{mailservice.selectedMessage.text}" style="font-weight:bold" escape="false" />
```

At that point, you will have invalid HTML since there is a `html` tag in your included content. One way to avoid this is to add an `iframe`

```
<iframe id="mailContent" src="about:blank"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var doc = document.getElementById("mailContent").contentWindow.document;
    doc.open();
    doc.write('<h:outputText value="#{mailservice.selectedMessage.text}" escape="false" />');
    doc.close();
</script>
```

Credit for `iframe` : [Specifying content of an iframe instead of the src to a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199458/specifying-content-of-an-iframe-instead-of-the-src-to-a-page)

**More info :**

- [h:outputText](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/outputText.html)

Comment: thankyou very much it works perfectly but i get other problem .. the message not  show complitly because p:dialog haven't scroll barr to scroll botom so how  can i add scroll bar to p:dialog

Comment: @user3151841 Well you can make the `iframe` scroll by adding `scrolling="yes"` should do the trick. You will also be able to change it's size with `width` and `height`. Remembe to mark as accepted if of course it meets your requirements.