# Is it possible to have inline iframe in html5?

Tags: html, iframe

In html code, is it possible to load an iframe without a src where the content is hardcoded in the html, kinda like this

```
<iframe>
     <html> 
         ....  (standard html content)
     </html>
</iframe>
```

Comment: You can find the answer to your question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199458/specifying-content-of-an-iframe-instead-of-the-src-to-a-page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specifying content of an iframe instead of the src to a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199458/specifying-content-of-an-iframe-instead-of-the-src-to-a-page)