# How to put PHP content into an iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, textarea

I have an `iframe` and I want to put PHP content in it like in a text-area.

```
<textarea><?php echo $content; ?></textarea>
```

But it does not work for an `iframe`. How can I solve it?

**Code:**

```
<form action="php_parsers/article_parser.php" id="writearticle" name="writearticle" method="POST">
    <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 22px;">Create Article</p>
    <textarea name="title" id="title" type="text" maxlength="100" placeholder="Article Title"></textarea>
    <div class="toolbar">
        <a onclick="iBold()"><i class='fa fa-bold'></i></a>
        <a onclick="iUnderline()"><i class='fa fa-underline'></i></a>
        <a onclick="iItalic()"><i class='fa fa-italic'></i></a>
        <a onclick="iFontSize()"><i class='fa fa-font'></i></a>
        <a onclick="iForeColor()"><i class='fa fa-align-left'></i></a>
        <a onclick="iHorizontalRule()"><i class='fa fa-align-center'></i></a>
        <a onclick="iUnorderedList()"><i class='fa fa-list-ul'></i></a>
        <a onclick="iOrderedList()"><i class='fa fa-list-ol'></i></a>
        <a onclick="iLink()"><i class='fa fa-link'></i></a>
        <a onclick="iUnlink()"><i class='fa fa-chain-broken'></i></a>
        <a onclick="iJustLeft()"><i class='fa fa-align-left'></i></a>
        <a onclick="iJustCenter()"><i class='fa fa-align-center'></i></a>
        <a onclick="iJustRight()"><i class='fa fa-align-right'></i></a>
        <a onclick="iImage()"><i class='fa fa-picture-o'></i></a>
    </div>
    <!-- Hide(but keep) normal textarea and place in the iFrame replacement for it -->
    <textarea style="display:none;" name="myTextArea" id="myTextArea" cols="100" rows="14"></textarea>
    <iframe name="richTextField" id="richTextField"></iframe>
    <!-- End replacing normal textarea -->
    <br />
    <br />
    <button id="article_btn" onclick="saveArticle()">Save Article</button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specifying content of an iframe instead of the src to a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199458/specifying-content-of-an-iframe-instead-of-the-src-to-a-page)

Comment: I've already tried it, but didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this and it works fine:

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML = '<iframe id="frame"></iframe>';
var frame = document.getElementById('frame').contentWindow.document;
frame.open();
frame.write('<html><body>It Works!</body></html>');
frame.close();
```

You can do this also on already rendered iframe.

Comment: And is that also possible to put a dynamic php variable inside the frame write like `frame-write('<?php echo $content; ?>');`?

Comment: And I think you should use `frame.close` instead of `doc.close`, but I tried it and also work with php!