# How to append a HTML markup via Chrome Extension without leaking styles of the host page to the appended element?

Tags: html, css, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome extension that would prevent me from visiting time-wasting websites.

Whenever I visit such website I would like to append an element to the `body` that will stay `position:fixed` on top of the page.

What I'm struggling with is that often styles from the **original page are leaking towards my appended markup**.

#### 1.

One solution could be using **iframe** but we have 2019 and I've been living under a rock for a year or two and as I'm returning to web development everything is React, virtual DOM, CSS4 who knows.

Here I've found a solution using **iframe**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4199540

```
  function writeToFrame() {
    var doc = document.getElementById('testing').contentWindow.document;
    doc.open();
    doc.write('<html><head><title></title><style>body{ background: blue }</style></head><body>Hello world.</body></html>');
    doc.close();
  }
```

It works, the `background: blue` is not leaking.

I'm worried that using iframes can bring some difficulties further down the line - namely communicating with the extension scripts.

#### 2.

Option two would be using `reset.css` but it doesn't work:
[image]

**Do you have maybe better ideas, maybe there is something obvious that I'm missing?**

Comment: You can use ShadowDOM, see [How to really isolate stylesheets in the Google Chrome extension?](//stackoverflow.com/q/12783217), or just plain overwrite the page using document.write() in your content script.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks! I was looking for that question, mark mine as duplicate :)