# How to print console.log inside script tag of iframe for react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

I have added one html file into iframe with script tag. And I am not able to see console.log inside script tag in react js. alert() also not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: will you please show the code ?

Comment: I fear you might be misusing the `<inframe>` element... Would you provide us with some code exceprt? I suspect somthing like `<inframe [...]> <script> [...] </script> </iframe>` which won't work. I'd recommend you https://stackoverflow.com/a/45000684/3748178